# Is it possible to preview an apps market page before publishing?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm getting ready to publish an app on the Android market, and I've created the promotional images and screenshots for it.  Before I publish though, it would be nice to see what the market page would look like.  Is there some way to preview it?

Comment: +1 generally relevant question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make corrections to some marketpage textual contents after publishing. You just cannot edit your app, without making another release.

Comment: It was a difficult choice but I guess you win! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way you can see a preview. If you don't like something after publishing it, unpublish it, make changes and publish it again. :)